# Keyboard shortcut for Always On Top

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

In ubuntu 13.10 (Unity Desktop Environment) there are keyboard shortcut like `ctrl + Super + Up` to maximize the windows etc.

Is there any keyboard shortcuts for `Always On Top` ?
If not how can make my own custom shortcut for the same using the ubuntu system setting?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Unity, but in XFCE I use `wmctrl` with a keyboard shortcut.

Basically you create a custom keyboard shortcut, mine is `CTRL-ALT-t` and send it to the program. The command for the Application to bring to top is:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above
```

You will probably have to install `wmctrl` first as I don't think it comes standard:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Credit goes to [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499362)